# Почему съезжает всплывающее окно?

Tags: html, css

При нажатии кнопки Заказать звонок у меня появляется окно с обратной связью, но сбиваются стили для .popup и я не понимаю почему. Для .popup я задал display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center, чтобы .popup-wrapper встал посередине. Для того, чтобы скрыть .popup я в медиазапросах просписал .popup { display: none; }, так как свойство display было уже занято. Вроде как все норм, но при повторном вызове окна,обнуляется свойство display: flex для .popup, а если выставить display: flex !important, то начинаются глюки: при закрытии окна оно появляется снова.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.request').click(function(event) {
    $('.popup').fadeIn();
  });

  $('.popup-close').click(function(event) {
      $('.popup').fadeOut();
  });

  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
      autoplay:true,
      slideSpeed: 9000,
      loop:true,
      nav: true,center:true,
      dots: true,
      responsiveClass:true,
      smartSpeed:400,
      margin:0,
      responsive:{
          0:{
              items:1,
              margin:0
          },
          800:{
              items:1
          },
          1100:{
              items:1
          },
          2000:{
              items:1
          }
      }
  });

});
```

```css
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Light', arial;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 310px;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*section main*/


.info {

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 120px;
  left: 80px;
  z-index: 70;
  padding: 20px;

}

.info-text {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.info-text h2 {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f0f0f0;

}
.info-text p {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
.info-button {
  background-color: #b36060;
  font-family: Lora;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.info-button:hover {
    outline: 2px solid white !important;
    
}

.arrow {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
/*sidebar*/
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 80;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 310px;
  background: #5b5858 url(../img/menu_bg.jpg) center repeat;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.logo {
  width: 245px;
  height: 76px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(197, 120, 64, 0.65);
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.logo h1 {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}
.logo span {
  position: absolute; 
  transform: translate(-15%, 80%);
  background: url(../img/menu_bg.jpg);
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 14.2px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.desc p {
  text-align: justify;
  letter-spacing: 1.4px;
  width: 245px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #aaa9a9;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.menu-main {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.menu-main ul li:nth-child(2):before {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  content: '1';
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: url(../img/rectangle.svg) center no-repeat;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.menu-main ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.menu-main ul li a:hover {
  color: #ff7200;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.menu-main li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #686464;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.menu-sub ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #bdbdbd;
}
.menu-sub ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.contact a.phone {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fefefe;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
.contact a.request {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #c57c40;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #c57c40;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.contact a.request:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
/*Slider*/


.img {
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
} 

.owl-nav {
  display: none;
}

.owl-dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}

.owl-dot {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #ffff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.owl-dot.active {
  transform: scale(1.8);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

/*Popup*/
.popup{
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: black;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 100;
}

.popup-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 980px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
   
}

.popup-form {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.popup-img img  {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-right: 40px;
}


.form-input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}


.popup-form h3 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.popup-form input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}
 

.popup-form  p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.popup-form input:focus, .popup-form textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #b75d5d;
}

.popup-form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}


.popup h3 {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.095em;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}

.popup sup {
  color: #b25252;
   font-size: 14px;
}

.popup p {

  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #716d6d;
}

.popup-form button.send {
  float: right;
  margin-right: -5px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  background-color: #db7d3a;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Lora;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
}


.popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #796454;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 200px) {
  .popup {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/clear.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/adaptive.css">
    <link href="https://allfont.ru/allfont.css?fonts=open-sans-light" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="https://allfont.ru/allfont.css?fonts=noto-sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/7dca09e227fdfe16908cebb4244589e4?family=Georgia" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="owl.carousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8e0bceeac7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Сияние - Декор центр</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="popup">

        <div class="popup-wrapper">
            
            <div class="popup-img">

                <img src="img/popup_img.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="popup-form">
                <button class="popup-close">&times;</button>
                <h3>обратная связь</h3>
                <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-input">
                        <p>E-mail <sup>*</sup></p>
                    <input type="email" name="user_email">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-input">
                        <p>Телефон <sup>*</sup></p>
                        <input type="tel" name="user_phone">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-input">
                        <p>Сообщение</p>
                        <textarea name="popup-message" id="popup-message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    
                     <button class="send" type="submit">Отправить</button>
                </form>

            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar">
            
                <div class="top-content">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="#">
                            <h1>сияние</h1>
                            <span>декор центр</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                        <div class="desc">
                            <p>Интернет-магазин отделочных материалов и дизайна</p>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>

                <div class="menu">

                    <div class="menu-main">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">каталог товаров</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">новости и акции</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">наши услуги</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">портфолио</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">блог</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">контакты</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="menu-sub">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Отзывы о нас</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Дизайнеры</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="contact">
                    <a href="tel:+78005118909" class="phone">+7 (4822) 648-080</a>
                    <a href="#" class="request">Заказать звонок</a>
                </div>
            
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="gallery">
                <div class="owl-carousel">
                    
                    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(img/bg-1.jpg);" class="div"></div>
                    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(img/bg-2.jpg);" class="div"></div>
                    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(img/bg-3.jpg);" class="div"></div>
                    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(img/bg-4.jpg);" class="div"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <div class="info-text">
                    <h2>Декоративные покрытия</h2>
                    <p>от лучших производителей</p>
                </div>
                <button class="info-button">Подробнее <span class="
arrow">&rarr;</span> </button>
            </div>

        </div>

    
        
    </div>

</body>
            
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну так где `fadeIn` - допиши, чтобы флекс ставился

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.request').click(function(event) {
    $('.popup').css({display:'flex'}).hide().fadeIn();
  });
```